# How does linux understand multiple periods in changing directories

Tags: command-line, files, zsh

I can do (say) `cd ...` to go back 2 directories but `...` is not listed in the output if I do `ls -a`. So how does linux understand that I want to go up 2 parent directories? I understand that `.` and `..` are like hard links to the current and parent directory.

Comment: Where are you getting that `cd ...` works?  This doesn't work by default, only `.` and `..` are accepted 'shortcuts' unless you have some special scripts or such set up...

Comment: That may be an alias or a function, please [edit] and provide the relevant lines from your dotfiles, you can find them with e.g.: `grep '\.\.\.' ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_aliases ~/.bash_functions`

Comment: ... or the OP is using `zsh` maybe?

Comment: @steeldriver I am actually using `zsh`, I didn't know this works only in zsh

Comment: @ThomasWard Seems like it was due to zsh. Didn't realize it was a shortcut there

Comment: @dessert Even for .zshrc, it gave me the output command not found. But I got my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @steeldriver Nice feature, would you write up an answer about it please? :)

Comment: @dessert I had to do a bit of rootling around, but it seems like they are aliases even in zsh (provided by `.oh-my-zsh/lib/directories.zsh`) - at least, that is the case on my system

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question as my initial question itself was flawed

Linux doesn't actually understand multiple periods. It's actually `zsh` which interprets it as going up multiple parent directories.

So if you are using `zsh` and are on say `/a/b/c` and use the command `cd ...`, it will take you back to `/a`. If you are using bash, it will correctly tell you that no such file or directory exists. It works the same way for other commands such as `ls` so you can actually do `ls ...` to see the files in the parent's parent directory. Just keep adding periods to go up one more parent.

It's a neat little feature hidden in zsh that I didn't know earlier. Thanks for the help everyone :)